# Teams Message Card Post Action Ignoring event from domain not in allow-list

Tags: microsoft-teams

Searched almost all the web ... last hope here ... ;-)

***Connectors: Ignoring event from domain not in allow-list*** << see debug log below

**Problem description:**

We have developed an teams office 365 connector. This connector sends a message card using the incoming web hook configured by the manifest. On this message card we have a POST action defined. When we press on this action a REST API call should be executed to a custom REST end point. The issue currently is that we are able to successful add the connector using the manifest and configuration page and we are able to successfully send an message card to the channel. But when we press the action the REST end point is not called at all and we get a "Forbidden message".

We have registered the connector using the portal: https://outlook.office.com/connectors/home/login/#/publish
And we have specified:

```
"Do you want to enable actions on your Connector cards?" -> YES

"Actions URL" -> "https://teamsrestapi.ngrok.io/RestAPI/Action"
```

We have created a manifest  with the correct whitelisting as:

```
"validDomains": [
    "teamsrestapi.ngrok.io"
  ]
```

And we are using the correct connector ID got from the connector portal.

**Configurations tried so far without luck:**

```
We have enabled in the Teams 'Org-wide setting' -> Users can communicate with other Skype for Business and Teams users
We have enabled in the Teams 'Org-wide setting' -> Users can communicate with Skype users
We have added in the Teams 'Org-wide setting'  the whitelisted Domain -> teamsrestapi.ngrok.io is Allowed
We have tried to deploy the app as an organisation wide app by putting it into the store
We checked all other network blocks whitelists etc.
We tried not to use ngrok but a Azure Webapp
```

**Question:**

Does anybody has an idea on how to put the domain into the correct allow list ? We also have tried to use a non ngrok address as a Azure Webapp but same error.

**Debug Logs:**
Below i pasted a part of the TEAMS debug log:

```
020-08-27T11:43:49.581Z Inf        [Scenario]ext_actionable_card_http_post [step](1)stop (173ms/173ms)
2020-08-27T11:43:49.580Z Err        [O365ActionPaneController.makeHttpPOSTRequestForConnector()] Http invoke failed: {"data":{"errorCode":"Forbidden"},"status":403,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/part/emea-02/beta/users/connectors/19:aaaaef3d98aaacfa817e3524bf5784f0@thread.tacv2;messageid=1598528625119/1598528625119/executeAction","data":{"inputParameters":[],"actionId":"aaaa4501-c054-49f4-b377-dc2b3f26c7d0","potentialAction":"{\"@type\":\"HttpPOST\",\"@i...
2020-08-27T11:43:49.579Z War        HTTP request  failed: POST "https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/part/emea-02/beta/users/connectors/19:aaaaaf3d98f34cfa817e3524bf5784f0@thread.tacv2;messageid=1598528625119/1598528625119/executeAction", status: 403, response: {"errorCode":"Forbidden"}, errorCode: Forbidden, requestId: undefined, correlationId: undefined, afdCorrelationId: Ref A: FB26054A0C7546D48003683B610E009D Ref B: AM3EDGE0714 Ref C: 2020-08-27T11:43:49Z
2020-08-27T11:43:49.578Z Inf        [Scenario]ext_actionable_card_http_post [step](0)error (164ms)
2020-08-27T11:42:57.574Z Inf        [Scenario]ext_sdkHelper_created [step](4)ext_sdkHelper_apiInvoked (2057ms)
2020-08-27T11:42:57.477Z Err        ngClickDecorator: value not found in enum type. value: 
2020-08-27T11:42:55.529Z Inf        Connectors: Ignoring event from domain not in allow-list - https://teamsrestapi.ngrok.io
2020-08-27T11:42:55.517Z Inf        [Scenario]ext_sdkHelper_created [step](3)ext_sdkHelper_apiInvoked (82ms)
2020-08-27T11:42:55.487Z Inf        Connectors: Ignoring event from domain not in allow-list - https://teamsrestapi.ngrok.io
2020-08-27T11:42:55.474Z Inf        Connectors: Ignoring event from domain not in allow-list - https://teamsrestapi.ngrok.io
2020-08-27T11:42:55.453Z Inf        Connectors: Ignoring event from domain not in allow-list - https://teamsrestapi.ngrok.io
2020-08-27T11:42:55.444Z Inf        Connectors: Received event - handleMessageSuccess
2020-08-27T11:42:55.436Z Inf        Connectors: Received event - unhandledMessage
2020-08-27T11:42:55.435Z Inf        [Scenario]ext_sdkHelper_created [step](2)ext_sdkHelper_apiInvoked (53ms)
2020-08-27T11:42:55.427Z Inf        Connectors: Received event - unhandledMessage
2020-08-27T11:42:55.418Z Inf        Connectors: Received event - handleMessageSuccess
2020-08-27T11:42:55.406Z Inf        Connectors: Received event - handleMessageSuccess
2020-08-27T11:42:55.386Z Inf        Connectors: Ignoring event from domain not in allow-list - https://teamsrestapi.ngrok.io
```

Manifest used:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.6/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.6",
  "id": "aaf6fb9b-5d8c-4c12-b5e1-3ea8c5d8a7d1",
  "version": "1.0.14",
  "packageName": "com.Teams.Connector.WEB",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Developer",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.xxxx.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.xxxx.com",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.xxxx.com"
  },
  "description": {
    "full": "OpsLogix Teams Connector WEB",
    "short": "Connector WEB"
  },
  "icons": {
     "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "aaaaabc5-8b41-41b3-94f1-1bdb70e2cb84",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "configurationUrl": "https://teamsrestapi.ngrok.io/configuration"
    }
  ],
  "name": {
    "full": "Teams.Connector.WEB",
    "short": "Teams.Connector.WEB"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "validDomains": [
    "teamsrestapi.ngrok.io"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your app manifest with us?

Comment: hi , thanks for responding , i updated my initial post with the manifest used. I changed the connector ID with aaaa in the begining.

Comment: Hi @Gousia-MSFT any suggestions yet ;-) ?

Comment: @michel, Is your connector in same tenant as your subscription? Is your connector approved?

Comment: @Manish-MSFT yes same tenant (i used the teams developer subscription) . What do you mean with approved ? I used [link](https://outlook.office.com/connectors/home/login/#/publish) to create the connector and the status is "Pending Approval' . If i need to approve it where do i do that ? Thanks

Comment: Can you please send the manifest to us at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com. Thanks.